# How to store videos in database and access them in windows application

Tags: c#, database, wpf, winforms

I have come across scenario where client want a windows application which will play videos from database.

In case web application, videos can be store on server and access from application.

But what about windows application? What is the preferred and effective way of storing videos in database in case of windows application? (There will be around 500 videos).

Which database should I use?

Any pointers/suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't save the videos in a database, that's a very bad idea. Save them in a media server that will be accessable to all clients via authentication.

Comment: But for that user need to connect to internet right? What about offline mode?

Comment: Why internet? You are talking about winform application, so save the videos in a network directory on a media server.

Comment: OK..But users are not under the same network. They are like based in different locations.

Comment: That doesn't matter. And if you store it in a database? How will they access the database? Same idea for storing on a network path. If the users are on a different network, you need to open a rule anyway.

Comment: Okk..I got what you are saying. Let me think over it and come back. Thanks for suggestions. Appreciated.

Comment: I also posted this as an anwer, accepting it as correct would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't store in database, but store on your server's filesystem, then provide access to them via simple http api.

Answer (score 3):

Don't save the videos in a database, that's a very bad idea. Saving and reading videos as BLOB from a database will result in poor performance. Since you are using a winform application, save the video files in a network directory on a media server that will be accessable to all clients via authentication or via directory permissions.